# UWP - BitMapImage to Icon

Tags: c#, uwp, icons, bitmapimage

I'm trying to make a UWP with Visual Studio 2017. I want to add as a  [NavigationViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem) the Microsoft Account Information. In order to do it I get with [GraphServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.services.microsoftgraph.microsoftgraphservice?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) the DisplayName and the profile picture saved as string and `BitMapImage` respectively.

What I would like to do is to crop circularly the `BitMapImage` and use it in the `Icon` property of the [`NavigationViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem).

Comment: You should probably show the code you already have to make the question clearer and more attractive. And you should definitely explain what stops you (*What I would like to do is to crop circularly the Bitmapimage and use in the Icon property of the NavigationViewItem.*) – there's currently no question asked in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like to do is to crop circularly the BitMapImage and use it in the Icon property of the NavigationViewItem.

You could not use `BitmapImage` as NavigationViewItem's [Icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.icon), It only receives [IconElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.iconelement#remarks).

To achieve your target, you could directly do layout in `NavigationViewItem.Content` to show image and text. For example, you could use `Ellipse` and `ImageBrush` to show image in circle shape.

Here's a simple code sample:

```xml
<NavigationView>
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="SalahNavItem" Tag="Salah">
                <NavigationViewItem.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush x:Name="img"></ImageBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Text="Custom" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </NavigationViewItem.Content>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="AppsNavItem"  Content="Apps" Tag="apps">
            </NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```

```cs
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/car.png"));
img.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
```

[image]